# Ng2-Charts (docker build) crashes Angular 9 App on AWS

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, github-actions

I have been working on a project from few months, it has been working great until last week.
Suddenly it is crashing on component where i call ng2-chart service.
Error on production can be shown in attached image below:
[image]

I got error on local server by `ng serve --aot optimization=false` just one time which shows some Theme Service Null error, but now it is working perfectly on local and on netlify.

I have tried everything for AWS deployment, but I am failed to have any resolution on ng2-charts issue.

> Note: Using GITHUB Workflows action to deploy on AWS.

My Component Html Code for Chart:

```
<div class="chart-wrapper">
   <canvas [chartType]="doughnutChartType" [data]="getProductCategoryChartData()"
           [labels]="getProductCategoryChartsLabels()" [legend]="false"
                                [options]="chartOption" baseChart>
   </canvas>
</div>
```

component.ts code:

```
doughnutChartLabels: Label[] = [];
doughnutChartData: MultiDataSet = [];
doughnutChartType: ChartType = 'doughnut';
public chartOption = {
    cutoutPercentage: 69,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    elements: {
        arc: {
            borderWidth: 0,
        },
    },

};
```

This code is working on Netlify and local build.

Here is my Docker File Code:

```
#############
### build ###
#############

# base image
FROM node:12.18.3 as build

RUN apt-get update

# set working directory | Root directory name not Folder in Dist
WORKDIR /<my-app-name>

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /<my-app-name>/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /<my-app-name>/package.json
RUN npm install
#RUN npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.23
# RUN npm install ngx-bootstrap@5.3.2

# add app
COPY . /<my-app-name>

## run tests
#RUN ng test --watch=false
#RUN ng e2e --port 4202

# generate build
#RUN node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --output-path=dist --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer

RUN node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot --optimization=false --buildOptimizer=false

############
### prod ###
############

# base image
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
# Clean nginx
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

ARG API_BASE_URL
ARG API_VERSION
ARG ENV
ARG IMAGE_TAG
ARG IMAGE_TAG_REF
ARG WEB_STATIC_RESOURCES_URL

ENV API_BASE_URL=$API_BASE_URL
ENV API_VERSION=$API_VERSION
ENV ENV=$ENV
ENV IMAGE_TAG=$IMAGE_TAG
ENV IMAGE_TAG_REF=$IMAGE_TAG_REF
ENV WEB_STATIC_RESOURCES_URL=$WEB_STATIC_RESOURCES_URL

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY --from=build /<my-app-name>/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Permission
RUN chown root /usr/share/nginx/html/*
RUN chmod 755 /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# run nginx
CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
# CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and here is my package.json file:

```
"version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.14.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.3",
    "ng2-charts": "~2.2.0",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.2.3",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.2.4",
    "ngx-mask": "^8.1.7",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/angular": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-charts-schematics": "^0.1.7",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
```